# Android CameraX - Autocapture image when camera is detecting a shape on screen

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera, android-camerax, google-mlkit

Our team previously built a feature years ago that uses Android's Camera2 API. Basically after opening the image preview it uses OpenCV to do a set of complicated calculations and detect when a user is pointing the camera at a document of particular proportions, and when focused, automatically capture the image of the document. I am trying to update/future proof this feature.

Basically I need to figure out how to auto capture an image when a rectangle is on screen.

I am hoping CameraX and the Image Analysis feature can provide an easier means of achieving this, but most times my search results bring me to MLKit, which seems like overkill for just detecting a simple shape.

The document content is incredibly variable and could be different text and images, but the paper itself will always have the same rectangular shape.

What would be the most straight forward way of achieving this?

Comment: Can this github project help you? https://github.com/dpchami/nidalib

Answer (score 0):

While you can hopefully significantly simplify your camera control code by moving to using CameraX instead of Camera2 directly, CameraX doesn't have any image processing functionality.

So you'd still need all your OpenCV code to detect paper edges, once you get an Image from CameraX's ImageAnalysis use case.

Certainly I'd expect MLKit could be used to train a classifier for this as well, but I don't know if that would really give you a simpler solution given that you already have one that works.